# Find string between two sets of characters or 3rd and 4th quotation marks

Tags: regex, string, beautifulsoup

I have been playing with `Beautifulsoup` and `re` to collect only the links I need from a webpage.

I was able to cut the page content to a `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`

This dataset contains the names of athletes and links to their profiles.

Now, I am using a for loop to print out the information of each individual.

The type of each iteration of the for loop is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`

Each element in the for loop looks something like this

```
</span>, <span class="txt-blue">
<a href="https://www.eliteprospects.com/player/70215/riley-nash">Riley Nash (F)</a>
              <a href="https://www.eliteprospects.com/league/wjc-18-w/team-captaincy/2021-2022">“A”</a>
```

I would like to extract only the first link `https://www.eliteprospects.com/player/70215/riley-nash` but not the 2nd.

I was hoping I could define `<a href=` as the start and the first occurrence of `>`as the end to extract the first link.

I also tried using the fact that the first link of each iteration of the for loop is going to be sandwiched between the 3rd and 4th quotation marks.

I have looked into reg and other methods and tried converting `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` to `str` but still wasn't able to figure out how to extract links.

Answer (score 0):

If `my_result_set` holds your `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>` you can do:

```py
for tag in my_result_set:
    print(tag.a["href"])
```

This should print the `href=` of first `<a>` tag.